# CSRF protection in browser extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, csrf, safari-extension, csrf-protection

I need to implement CSRF protection for my site. So I started implementing this for all forms from my site, but I have problems with implementation of it in browsers extensions (Chrome, Safari, Firefox). I have no ideas how to do this for posts from my extensions(forms and ajax posts). Had anyone implemented this ever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here are some things that I saw people actually use - in my function as addons.mozilla.org (code) reviewer:

1. Design a proper API. There are tons of resources on SO and the web, e.g. detailing how to properly build e.g. Restful APIs and secure them against CSRF. The thing to keep in mind is that extension APIs in contrast to regular web pages provide XHR that either doesn't care same-origin or let you define a set of locations the extension is allowed to access. Hence extension-specific APIs not need to implement CORS, which shrinks the attack surface on such APIs quite a bit. Of course, it would be better to go the extra-mile and ensure your API is secure even with CORS.
2. Designing a full web API can take quite a lot of time. I saw people build a very minimal one: The API consists of a single method to get the CSRF token to be used with the regular not-very-APIy existing forms.
3. If you cannot implement a proper API, because e.g. it's not your site/code or you simply lack the time, resources and/or skills to learn about and then design and implement an API, there is still another way: Just web-scrape the site (XHR + regex usually) and get the CSRF token that way. Again, extensions do not have to abide same-origin, so web-scraping is always a possibility, while web sites cannot do the same thing unless allowed by CORS.
4. Almost forgot: Some extensions are nothing more than a button that will open a regular webpage on the server - not necessarily in a regular tab, but often in some kind of panel as provided by the extension API you're dealing with.

Comment: the same ideas I had too. So there is no other solution?

Comment: You can only use the "APIs" the server provides. And since it is an http server (serving html right now), you'd use that and I suggested the things people actually use. Or roll another API over UDP datagrams if you like. But in the end, there needs to be some API/interface the extension can interact with.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go to work and implement this way. Thanks a lot!